I have written a apex trigger on task and want a test class code
if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if (t.WhatId != null && t.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
            oppIds.add(t.WhatId);
        }
    }
}

   if (!oppIds.isEmpty()) {
    OpportunityHelper.updateActivityLastModifiedDate(oppIds);
}


Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the quick two minute [tour]. Your question, as written, is not in an acceptable format. Our guidelines require questions to show some effort. In this case, you should include any code you've already written trying to cover this code, and where you're stuck. You can [edit] your question to include additional information, and we'll be happy to help you get your unit test working.

How Do I Write an Apex Unit Test, one of our [tag:canonical-qa] tagged questions is a good place to start. Well, the Unit Testing on the Lightning Platform module on Trailhead is the good place to start, but the canonical-qa question links to that module and provides a bit more detail and additional links.

You may use this sample code to cover your apex trigger code.
https://www.decodeforce.com/code/-O-iLf4LtAsb0C0fXIFO
